# Java equivalent to R iPlots package (alternative to Mondrian)

Tags: java, r, bigdata, mondrian

One demonstrated me the power of R [iPlot](http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/iplots/) package : you plot the same individual data two different ways, and when selecting data on one figure, it selects the matching data on the other figure.

Eg: let's take people age distribution on one plot, and gender on a bar chart.

- If you select all male individual on bar chart, it will highlight you all male ages on the other plot.
- If you select some points on age distribution plot, it will highlight matching proportion
  within bar charts.

It seems like [Mondrian](http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/mondrian/) package do the same, but is not supported since 2011. 
Do you use successfully a full Java alternative or equivalent to those ? (I have to get rid of R from my application).

Thanks !

Comment: To illustrate my question, here is some similar application through java script. Still looking toward a recent alternative in Java ...: http://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/visuel/2014/06/06/les-artistes-ont-ils-vraiment-plus-de-risque-de-mourir-a-27-ans_4433903_4355770.html (it is made thanks to this : http://raphaeljs.com/)